# Eclipse Specific: Is it possible to find references of use of derived methods in a class?

Tags: eclipse

I have a class Ca which extends Cb. Method M1 is implemented in the parent (Cb). However when invoked by classes, they would typically have called Ca.M1(). I want to find all such occurrences.

Eclipse has a feature 'Find references' (Shortcut: CTRL+SHIFT+G). However, it only works on actual methods defined in a class and not on derived methods.

Is there a an easier way search for this method use in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

Try this plugin. This is absolutely awesome and horribly hard to understand. But anyway fun, and would do your task. http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/browse-query

This plugin indexes your code, and then you can make queries of it. Even really complicated ones.
Example to impress you:

not exists ( matching "serialVersionUID" fields in ) recursive derived classes of class "Persistent"

This stands for finding classes not having serialVersionUID and being the descendant (not just children) of "Persistent" class.

Have fun with it.

Answer (score 1):

Try [nWire for Java](http://www.nwiresoftware.com/). It gives you all possible associations within your code, for derived methods as well.